# How to output an interger which is calculated to two decimal places?

Tags: c++, c++11

It is easy to output a double value which is calculated to two decimal places.
And the code snippet is below:

```
cout.setf(ios_base::showpoint);
cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield);
cout.precision(2);
cout << 10000000.2 << endl;       // output: 10000000.20
cout << 2.561452 << endl;         // output: 2.56
cout << 24 << endl;               // output: 24         but I want 24.00, how to change my code?
```

How to output an interger which is calculated to two decimal places? I want 24.00 as an output.

Comment: cout << 24  << ".00" << endl;

Comment: Integers, by definition, have no fractional part. So as R2RT said, just write ".00" after the number yourself.

Comment: `cout << (double)24 << endl,`:

Comment: @R2RT, I half expected someone to go on this long winded explanation of how to cast to float and include decimals. And I get your answer. I'm lucky it's the end of the day in the office, otherwise people would be concerned at my laughing fit and I'd be fired. Thank you so much for brightening up my evening, mate

Comment: Personally I'd plump for a class that wraps the type, and with an appropriate `ostream` overload for `<<` so, at the point of use, you can use `cout << foo(24) << endl;`, and, for an integer, it merely appends `".00"`.

Comment: @R2RT Your answer is right, but not elegant.

Comment: Arguably @R2RT's answer is more correct: as soon as you have a 64-bit integer > 2^53, you will start running into trouble if you convert to `double`

Comment: @JamesWhyte I just wanted to share my 5s solution, I was sure someone will write pretty explicit answer. I have never met the `cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield)` yet, so digging into documentation would take more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your 24 is.

If it is a hard-coded value, you can just write:

```
std::cout << 24.00 << std::endl;
```

If it's an integer variable, write this:

```
std::cout << static_cast<double>(myIntegerVariable) << std::endl;
```

Don't use any of the suggested approaches like adding ".00" as this will break your code if you want to change the precision later.

Comment: It's not really about changing the precision, but the *type*. Adding ".00" is acceptable therefore IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

A rewrite of completeness, please try with following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int i = 24;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << double(i) << std::endl;
    //    Output:  24.00
}
```